# Matrix changed in vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix [1,n], and I would like to understand why it changes itself in a vector when I remove some values of it.

Here is an illustration example of my problem:

```
> mat<-matrix(seq(1:10),1,10)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

`mat` is a matrix [1,10]

```
> mat<-mat[,which(mat[1,]!=10)]
> mat
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`mat` is now a vector [9]

Comment: `mat <- mat[, which(mat[1,] != 10), drop = FALSE]` Please study `help("[")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Add `drop=FALSE` as in `mat[i,j,drop=FALSE]`

---

Long answer:

An excerpt from pages 202-203 of *Software for Data Analysis* by John Chambers:

[W]atch out for selecting a single row or column. In this case there is some question about whether the user wanted a matrix result or a vector containing the single row or column. Both options are provided, and the choice is controlled by a special argument to the '[' operator, `drop=`.  If this is `TRUE`, single rows and columns have their dimension "dropped", returning a vector; otherwise a matrix is always returned. The default is and has always been `drop=TRUE`; probably an unwise decision on our part long ago, but now one of those back-compatibility burdens that are unlikely to be changed.

Similarly, in his book *The Art of R Programming*, Norman Matloff titles Section 4.6 (the section that addresses this issue) as "Dimension Reduction: a Bug or a Feature?".